# Online mssql server sync using Microsoft Sync Framework

Tags: sql, database, microsoft-sync-framework

Good Day,

I have a scenario wherein I have 1 branch company and 1 Main office, the server is at the main office with SQL Server 2008 installed on it, on the branch, I have sql server express installed on a client. I wouldn't recommend using an online app since the internet speed on the branch is very slow. I would like to ask if Microsoft Sync Framework is able to sync the two databases online. If so, can you give me references, Sample Code or tips on how to implement microsoft sync framework on this kind of scenario.

Thank You,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation that comes with the framework should give you enough to get started already. If you want an n-tier setup, there's a sample [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Database-SyncSQL-Server-e97d1208)